# Avoid anonymous inner classes in GWT command pattern

Tags: class, gwt, command, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I use GWT-dispatcher for my GWT-app to get the benefits of command-pattern. As the number of server calls grows the number of anonymous inner classes also grows and clutters the code. Is there a design tip on how to extract these anonymous inner classes and their onSuccess and onFailure from the rest of the code (in my case the Activity)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare *named* inner classes instead. These classes can even be static if they don't need to access the instance of the outer class, though this is not important for code to be compiled by GWT.